# My lambda function don't add data on first trigger after deployment , then it works perfectly

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

here is my code , i don't know why but it's really weird !
i had tried various way to send my data to my dynamoDb , i thought it may be the batchwhrite function but i m following exactly the documentation

i m sorry but i'm still a beginner and this problem rly took longer than it should be

```
const parse = require('csvtojson');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const csv = require('@fast-csv/parse');
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-north-1" });

exports.handler = async (event) => {

   const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
    const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    const params = {
        Bucket: bucket,
        Key: key,
    }; 
    function Chunknig(arrayList) {
    while (arrayList.length> 25) {
        arrayOflists.push(arrayList.splice(0, 25));
    }
    arrayOflists.push(arrayList)  
    }
    function batching(arrayof25) {  
        documentClient.batchWrite(arrayof25, function(err, data) {
      if (err) {
          console.log(err); 
      } 
      else  {
          console.log('Added  items to DynamoDB');
      }   
    });

    }
      
      const csvFile = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
      let array = [];
      let arrayOflists = []
      let parserFcn = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const parser = csv
          .parseStream(csvFile, { headers: true })
          .on("data", function (data) {
            array.push(data)
         
          })
          .on("end", function () {
            resolve("csv parse process finished");
          })
          .on("error", function () {
            reject("csv parse process failed");
          });
      });
    
      try {
        await parserFcn;
       
      } catch (error) {
        console.log("Get Error: ", error);
      }
      
       Chunknig(array)
      
        arrayOflists.forEach( async (itemList) =>{
        const single_array ={ 
        RequestItems: {
          "itemservice-4mu7wtjf7fgs7pzud2s4o6v25q-staging": []
         }
        }
        
        itemList.forEach(
        (item)=>{
       
            single_array.RequestItems['itemservice-4mu7wtjf7fgs7pzud2s4o6v25q-staging'].push(
                { PutRequest: {
              Item: { id: item.id ,
                    ...item
                              } 
              },}
          )
        }
    )
    

  batching(single_array)

  
      
        } )
    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
  
        body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!' ),
    };
    return response;
};
```

i had tried various way to send my data to my dynamoDb , i thought it may be the batchwhrite function but i m following exactly the documentation

i m sorry but i'm still a beginner and this problem rly took longer than it should be

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that you are not waiting for the write to finish before your lambda function completes it's execution.

The `documentClient.batchWrite` method is asynchronous and you need to wait for it to finish before allowing your lambda function to complete. Since you've made your lambda handler `async`, the easiest way is to convert this to use promises, and await the result of each batch write. All the `aws-sdk` methods allow you to call `.promise()` at the end to get one instead of using a callback.

You can also add a third parameter to your event handler (the `callback`) and invoke it when your work is complete, this is the older way of doing things, however.

Here is how you might modify your function to use promises. Pay particular note to how the `batching` function has changed and how we now have to `await` it later on.

```
const parse = require('csvtojson');
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const s3 = new AWS.S3();
const csv = require('@fast-csv/parse');
const documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
AWS.config.update({ region: "eu-north-1" });

exports.handler = async (event) => {

  const bucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const key = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, ' '));
  const params = {
    Bucket: bucket,
    Key: key,
  };

  function Chunknig(arrayList) {
    while (arrayList.length> 25) {
        arrayOflists.push(arrayList.splice(0, 25));
    }
    arrayOflists.push(arrayList)
  }

  function batching(arrayof25) {
    // Note: Callback removed, using .promise() at the end and returning it!
    return documentClient.batchWrite(arrayof25).promise();
  }

  const csvFile = s3.getObject(params).createReadStream();
  let array = [];
  let arrayOflists = []
  let parserFcn = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const parser = csv
      .parseStream(csvFile, { headers: true })
      .on("data", function (data) {
        array.push(data)

      })
      .on("end", function () {
        resolve("csv parse process finished");
      })
      .on("error", function () {
        reject("csv parse process failed");
      });
  });

  try {
    await parserFcn;

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Get Error: ", error);
  }

  Chunknig(array)

  // Note: Changed to a map, wrapped in promise.all
  await Promise.all(arrayOflists.map( async (itemList) => {
    const single_array = {
      RequestItems: {
        "itemservice-4mu7wtjf7fgs7pzud2s4o6v25q-staging": []
      }
    }

    itemList.forEach((item)=>{

      single_array.RequestItems['itemservice-4mu7wtjf7fgs7pzud2s4o6v25q-staging'].push({
        PutRequest: {
          Item: {
            id: item.id ,
            ...item
          }
        }
      })
    })

    // Note: now we await the result of the ddb writes!
    await batching(single_array)
  }))

  const response = {
    statusCode: 200,

    body: JSON.stringify('Hello from Lambda!' ),
  };

  return response;
};
```